# EF Code First and modelbuilder - how to make a one-to-one relationship with the same ID?

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, one-to-one

I have two classes:

```
public class Account
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

   public PayoffData PayoffData {get;set;}
}

public class PayoffData
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   //some other fields
}
```

Now, i want class `PayoffData` to have the same id that class `Account` has, and it needs to be one-to-one relationship (account can (or can not) have one payoffdata).

I've tried to do something with modelbuilder, but as far i can see that to set up a foreignkey in `PayoffData` class, i need to set a `.HasMany` relationship, which i don't want. How can i solve my problem using modelbuilder? (I don't want to use data annotations approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.PayoffData)
    .WithRequired();
```

Both tables will have a primary key column called `Id` and the primary key `Id` in the `PayoffData` table will be the foreign key to the `Account` table at the same time.